# In NetSuite, how can I access the deleted transaction lines using a saved search. Please mind that I don't need the deleted transaction records

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

In NetSuite, how can I access the deleted transaction lines using a saved search/report. Please mind that I don't need the deleted transaction records. I know there is a saved search object "Deleted Record" but that gives the deleted records and not the lines

Answer (score 0):

Using a saved search have you tried the "Line System Notes Fields..." option?  I did not see a "Type" or "Context" combination that might be a workaround way to identify deleted lines...  You'll have to get crafty since per NS, "The line-level audit trail does not track the initial creation or deletion of line items. Only updates to existing line items are tracked."  Reference Suite Answer [9052](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/9052/kw/9052) for more information.

Comment: Hi Martha, thanks for your reply. Yes, I have tried "Line system notes fields" option. It only  gives the changes made to the lines and hence it does not solve my problem. I am not able to capture the deleted lines of transactions which is my requirement. It required for account matching and downstream reporting. Hence, I am looking into scripting solution to achieve this, thanks a ton!!

Comment: That makes sense, this seems more difficult via saved search.  Via script, there are definitely many options using SuiteScript 2.x Client Script Entry Points (i.e. lineInit or sublistChanged functions or a combination of pageInit and saveRecord).   Using the currentRecord or Record modules, both objects have sublist methods (like getLineCount) that should be helpful.  Best of luck!